# How to import a subckt model into LTspice while it contains other subckt models itself?

Tags: ltspice, pspice

The following spice model refers to UCC28C43. The main subckt models (UCC28C43_STEADY and UCC28C43_START) contain other subckt models which are written in the continuation of the txt file. Is it enough to copy the file in the proper directory and create the symbol for the main subckt or are there other considerations required for sub-subckt models?

````
* PSpice Model Editor - Version 16.0.0
*$
*****************************************************************************
** This product is designed as an aid for customers of Texas Instruments.  **
** No warranties, either expressed or implied, with respect to this third  **
** party software (if any) or with respect to its fitness for any          **
** particular purpose is claimed by Texas Instruments or the author. The   **
** software (if any) is provided solely on an "as is" basis. The entire    **
** risk as to its quality and performance is with the customer             **
*****************************************************************************
*
* This model was developed for Texas Instruments Incorporated by:
*   AEi Systems, LLC
*   5777 W. Century Blvd., Suite 876
*   Los Angeles, California  90045
*
* This model is subject to change without notice. Neither Texas Instruments Incorporated 
* nor AEi Systems is responsible for updating this model.
* For more information regarding modeling services, model libraries and simulation 
* products, please call AEi Systems at (310) 216-1144, or contact AEi Systems by email: 
* info@AENG.com. Or visit AEi Systems on the web at http://www.AENG.com.
*
*****************************************************************************
*
* (C) Copyright 2008 Texas Instruments Incorporated. All rights reserved.
* Released by: Analog e-Lab Design Center, Texas Instruments Inc.
* Part: UCC28C43 (can be used for UCC38C43 also)
* Date: 11/05/2008
* Model Type: Transient Steady State
* Simulator: PSpice
* EVM Order Number: UCC38C44
* EVM Users Guide: slua274a, Oct 2008
* Datasheet: slus458d, Rev Jan 2007
*
*****************************************************************************
*
* Updates:
*
* Final 1.00
* Release to Web.
*
*****************************************************************************
.SUBCKT UCC28C43_STEADY  COMP   FB   CS   RTCT    GND    OUT   VDD   VREF  
****OSCILLATOR*****
STOF1 8 GND RTCT GND SOSC
GBDISCH RTCT GND Value = { IF ( V(8,GND) < 2.5 & V(13,GND) > 2.5, 8.4M, 0 ) }
RPULL 8 VREF 100K
****UVLO***********
STOF2 VDD 19 VDD GND SUVLO
RUVLO 19 GND 1MEG
RSTDBY VDD GND 309K ; startup current 
ROP 10 GND 2535 ; operating current
****REFERENCE*******
EBREF 13 GND Value = { IF ( V(19,GND) > 6, 5, 0 ) } 
RREG 10 VREF 0.158
CREF VREF GND 1N
V3 13 10 
**GB6 19 GND Value = { IF ( V(19,GND) > 4 , (I(V3)) , 0 ) }
GB6 19 GND Value = { IF (V(19,GND) > 4 , IF((I(V3)-I(EMY19))>2,
+ 2, IF((I(V3)-I(EMY19))<0, 0,(I(V3)-I(EMY19)))), 0 ) }
****CURRENT COMPARATOR*******
EB3 21 GND Value = { IF ( V(CS,GND) > V(16,GND), 5, 0 ) }
R7 CS GND 1MEG
RDELAY 21 22 1K
CDELAY 22 GND 200P
****ERROR AMPLIFIER**********
XAMP VREF FB COMP GND 28C4xAMP
****OFFSET LIMITER***********
R4 12 11 2MEG
R6 11 GND 1MEG
EB2 16 GND Value = { IF ( V(11,GND) > 1, 1, V(11,GND) ) }
V4 COMP 9 1
D1 9 12 D2
****OUTPUT DRIVER************
EMY19 191 GND VALUE = {V(19,GND)} 
XDRIVE 191 GND 5 OUT FETOUTC4X ; FETOUTC4X 2845OUT 
****S-R LATCH****************
XLATCH 8 VREF 22 GND 6 7 FFLOPC2
****OUTPUT AND GATE**********
EOut 5 GND Value = { IF ( V(VREF,GND) > 2.5 & V(7,GND) > 
+2.5 & V(8,GND) > 2.5, 5, 0 ) }
.MODEL SOSC VSWITCH (RON=.01 ROFF=1MEG VT=1.45 VH=0.95) ; VT=1.45 set to match 53k @ 3.3n/10k
.MODEL SUVLO VSWITCH (RON=.01 ROFF=10MEG VT=8.0 VH=0.4)
.MODEL D2 D 
.ENDS UCC28C43_STEADY











*$
*****************************************************************************
** This product is designed as an aid for customers of Texas Instruments.  **
** No warranties, either expressed or implied, with respect to this third  **
** party software (if any) or with respect to its fitness for any          **
** particular purpose is claimed by Texas Instruments or the author. The   **
** software (if any) is provided solely on an "as is" basis. The entire    **
** risk as to its quality and performance is with the customer             **
*****************************************************************************
*
* This model was developed for Texas Instruments Incorporated by:
*   AEi Systems, LLC
*   5777 W. Century Blvd., Suite 876
*   Los Angeles, California  90045
*
* This model is subject to change without notice. Neither Texas Instruments Incorporated 
* nor AEi Systems is responsible for updating this model.
* For more information regarding modeling services, model libraries and simulation 
* products, please call AEi Systems at (310) 216-1144, or contact AEi Systems by email: 
* info@AENG.com. Or visit AEi Systems on the web at http://www.AENG.com.
*
*****************************************************************************
*
* (C) Copyright 2008 Texas Instruments Incorporated. All rights reserved.
* Released by: Analog e-Lab Design Center, Texas Instruments Inc.
* Part: UCC28C43 (can be used for UCC38C43 also)
* Date: 11/05/2008
* Model Type: Transient Startup
* Simulator: PSpice
* EVM Order Number: UCC38C44
* EVM Users Guide: slua274a, Oct 2008
* Datasheet: slus458d, Rev Jan 2007
*
*****************************************************************************
*
* Updates:
*
* Final 1.00
* Release to Web.
*
*****************************************************************************
.SUBCKT UCC28C43_START  COMP   FB   CS   RTCT    GND    OUT   VDD   VREF  
****OSCILLATOR*****
STOF1 8 GND RTCT GND SOSC
GBDISCH RTCT GND Value = { IF ( V(8,GND) < 2.5 & V(13,GND) > 2.5, 8.4M, 0 ) }
RPULL 8 VREF 100K
****UVLO***********
STOF2 VDD 19 VDD GND SUVLO
RUVLO 19 GND 1MEG
***CDUMMY 19 GND 0.01p
RSTDBY VDD GND 309K ; startup current 
ROP 10 GND 2535 ; operating current
****REFERENCE*******
EBREF 13 GND Value = { IF ( V(19,GND) > 6, 5, 0 ) } 
RREG 10 VREF 0.158
CREF VREF GND 1N
V3 13 10 
***GB6 19 GND Value = { IF ( V(19,GND) > 7 , I(V3) , 0 ) }
GB6 19 GND Value = { IF (V(19,GND) > 4 , IF((I(V3)-I(EMY19))>10e-3,
+ 10e-3, IF((I(V3)-I(EMY19))<0, 0,(I(V3)-I(EMY19)))), 0 ) }
****CURRENT COMPARATOR*******
EB3 21 GND Value = { IF ( V(CS,GND) > V(16,GND), 5, 0 ) }
R7 CS GND 1MEG
RDELAY 21 22 1K
CDELAY 22 GND 200P
****ERROR AMPLIFIER**********
XAMP VREF FB COMP GND 28C4xAMP
****OFFSET LIMITER***********
R4 12 11 2MEG
R6 11 GND 1MEG
EB2 16 GND Value = { IF ( V(11,GND) > 1, 1, V(11,GND) ) }
V4 COMP 9 1
D1 9 12 D2
****OUTPUT DRIVER************
EMY19 191 GND VALUE = {V(19,GND)} 
***XDRIVE 19 GND 5 OUT FETOUTC4X ; FETOUTC4X 2845OUT 
XDRIVE 191 GND 5 OUT FETOUTC4X ; FETOUTC4X 2845OUT 
****S-R LATCH****************
XLATCH 8 VREF 22 GND 6 7 FFLOPC2
****OUTPUT AND GATE**********
EOut 5 GND Value = { IF ( V(VREF,GND) > 2.5 & V(7,GND) > 
+2.5 & V(8,GND) > 2.5, 5, 0 ) }
.MODEL SOSC VSWITCH (RON=.01 ROFF=1MEG VT=1.45 VH=0.95) ; VT=1.45 set to match 53k @ 3.3n/10k
.MODEL SUVLO VSWITCH (RON=.01 ROFF=5MEG VT=8.0 VH=0.4)
.MODEL D2 D 
.ENDS UCC28C43_START
*$




















.SUBCKT 28C4xAMP  4     1    9   20
*                VREF  INV  OUT V-
R1 10 4 100K
R2 10 20 100K
R3 6 20 316MEG
C1 6 20 8.7p ; Bandwidth
E1 5 20 6 20 1
R4 1 20 50MEG ; Input Bias
I2 4 9 1m ; Isource
R6 20 3 300
Q1 20 13 9 QPMOD
I3 13 20 68U 
D14 3 13 DMOD
D15 20 6 DCLAMP
L1 2 3 10U
C2 3 20 200P
R9 5 2 5
C5 2 20 0.02U
G1 20 6 10 1 100U
.MODEL QPMOD PNP BF=217.647 ; sets the Isink current
.MODEL DCLAMP D (RS=10 BV=6.8 IBV=.01) 
.MODEL DMOD D
.ENDS 28C4xAMP
*$








.SUBCKT 2845OUT  4  7  3  12
*                +V -V IN OUT
I3 4 8 100U
D3 8 4 DMOD
D4 12 8 DMOD
Q3 8 1 9 QIN
Q4 12 9 7 QMOD
Q5 4 8 6 QMOD
I4 7 1 .9M
R1 3 2 10K
Q8 1 2 7 QIN
Q2 4 6 12 QMOD2
.MODEL QMOD NPN RC=1.5 RE=.5 RB=100 IKF=0.5 CJC=0.4P
.MODEL QMOD2 NPN TF=400P TR=400P
.MODEL QIN NPN BF=100 BR=2 IS=1E-16 VAF=50 
+ CJE=1.5P CJC=.15P TR=1N TF=4N
.MODEL DMOD D RS=1 IS=0.4U
.ENDS 2845OUT
*$










.SUBCKT FETOUTC4X  Vcc  Gnd In Out
*                  Vcc  -V  IN OUT
* simplify with b element with 5.5 ohms make it stiff vcc and zero
Rm1 Vcc Out 10MEG
M1 Vcc 3 Out Out _NMOS 
Rm2 Out Gnd 10MEG
M2 Gnd 3 Out Out _PMOS 
EB1 2 Out Value= { IF ( V(In,Gnd) > 2 , 5 , -5 ) }
R1 2 3 75
C2 3 Gnd 10p
C3 3 Vcc 10p
R2 3 Gnd 10Meg
.MODEL _NMOS NMOS KP=1 NSUB=1E9 RD=10 VTO=3
.MODEL _PMOS PMOS KP=1 RD=5.5 VTO=-3 NSUB=1E9
.ENDS FETOUTC4X
*$









.SUBCKT FFLOPC2 1  2 11 12 5  6
*              CLK D R  S  QB Q
X1 7 4 2 8 NAND3_0C2 
X2 8 3 10 9 NAND3_0C2 
X3 1 8 10 7 NAND3_1C2 
X4 4 9 1 10 NAND3_0C2 
X5 4 7 6 5 NAND3_1C2 
X6 5 10 3 6 NAND3_0C2 
X7 11 4 INV 
X8 12 3 INV 
.ENDS FFLOPC2
*$






.SUBCKT NAND3_0C2 1 2 3 4
E1 5 0 VALUE = { IF ( (V(1)>800M) & (V(2)>800M) & (V(3)>800M), 0, 5 ) }
R1 5 4 100
C1 4 0 20P IC=0
.ENDS NAND3_0C2 
*$





.SUBCKT NAND3_1C2 1 2 3 4
E1 5 0 VALUE = { IF ( (V(1)>800M) & (V(2)>800M) & (V(3)>800M), 0, 5 ) }
R1 5 4 100
C1 4 0 20P IC=3.5
.ENDS NAND3_1C2 
*$




.SUBCKT INV 1 2
E1 3 0 VALUE = { IF ( V(1)>800mV, 0, 5 ) }
R1 3 2 100
C1 2 0 10P IC=3.5
.ENDS INV
*$




*Diodes,Inc, Zener 10V-50V; 16.0V  1.00W   
.SUBCKT DI_SMAZ16  1   2
*     Terminals    A   K
D1 1 2 DF
DZ 3 1 DR
VZ 2 3 14.9
.MODEL DF D ( IS=25.7p RS=0.756 N=1.10
+ CJO=377p VJ=1.00 M=0.330 TT=50.1n )
.MODEL DR D ( IS=5.15f RS=0.460 N=1.49 )
.ENDS DI_SMAZ16  
*$







.SUBCKT FQB6N80   10 20 30
*     TERMINALS:  D  G  S
M1   1  2  3  3  DMOS L=1U W=1U
RD  10  1  0.711
RS  40  3  38.5m
RG  20  2  42.7
CGS  2  3  1.14n
EGD 12  0  2  1  1
VFB 14  0  0
FFB  2  1  VFB  1
CGD 13 14  180p
R1  13  0  1.00
D1  12 13  DLIM
DDG 15 14  DCGD
R2  12 15  1.00
D2  15  0  DLIM
DSD  3 10  DSUB
LS  30 40  7.50n
.MODEL DMOS  NMOS(LEVEL=1 LAMBDA=2.00m VTO=4.00 KP=8.40
.MODEL DCGD D (CJO=180p VJ=0.600 M=0.680
.MODEL DSUB D (IS=24.1n N=1.50 RS=77.6m BV=800
+ CJO=477p VJ=0.800 M=0.420 TT=650n
.MODEL DLIM D (IS=100U)
.ENDS FQB6N80
*$






.model D1N4148  D(Is=2.682n N=1.836 Rs=.5664 Ikf=44.17m Xti=3 Eg=1.11 Cjo=4p
+ M=.3333 Vj=.5 Fc=.5 Isr=1.565n Nr=2 Bv=100 Ibv=100u Tt=11.54n)
*$







.SUBCKT C94SA476X0020 2 4
R1 2 3 38.106M
C1 3 1 46.980U IC = 12
R3 5 4 150
R2 2 4 21.285MEG
R4 3 26 4.7633G
R6 3 7 4.7633K
C5 7 1 18.792U IC = 12
R7 3 10 47.633 
C6 10 1 18.792U IC = 12
R8 3 13 476.33M
C7 13 1 18.792U IC = 12
C2 26 1 18.792U IC = 12
R9 3 28 47.633MEG
C3 28 1 18.792U IC = 12
R10 3 29 476.33K
C4 29 1 18.792U IC = 12
L8 1 5 2.0000N
R24 1 5 114.32M
L12 5 4 10.0000N
.ENDS C94SA476X0020
*$

```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a file has more than one subcircuit within, and that subcircuit calls other subcircuits that reside within that same file, then all you need to do is to `.inc` or `.lib` that file while making sure that the symbol for the main sibcircuit uses the name of that subcircuit.

For this case, if the text file has the name `file.lib` (extension doesn't matter, it can be anything, even none), then add a SPICE directive (<kbd>S</kbd>) and write `inc file.lib`, or `.lib file.lib`, and change the name of the symbol to be `UCC28C43_STEADY`, or `UCC28C43_START`, depending on whichever one you plan on using.